# Excel Comparison in 2 sheets and highlight in different colour based on result

Tags: excel-formula

Suppose there are 2 sheets Run1 and Run2 in excel. Both have a column say PassCount. How can we compare PassCount on Run1 and Run2 for greater value such that, if PassCount in Run2 is higher than PassCount from Run1 then Run2 entry should be highlighted in green else it should be red

Edit: 
Run2
[image]

Run1
Run 1 is exactly same sheet with different values.

Now what I need is: If(C3 of sheet Run14 > C3 of sheet Run13) then highlight C3 of Run14 in green else highlight it in red. This will show if the current result is better than the previous result or not.

Comment: Are the values in the two sheets in the same order? Or do they need to be looked up via an ID column? Please post a screenshot of ten rows of each sheet and explain the expected result.

Comment: @teylyn Have added the edit. Does it clear things now ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a conditional formatting rule with a formula.

In the simplest of cases, the formula just needs to compare the cell in column C in the current row with the cell in column C in the other sheet, in the same row, so the formula would be as follows. Select your data from C3 down to the end of the data, then create a new conditional format that uses a formula and enter this formula:

```
=$C3>Run1!$C3
```

If the position of the different values can vary, though, this formula will produce false positives and false negatives. It would be much safer to look up the value that you want to compare, based on the identifier in column A. For this, you can use the formula:

```
=VLOOKUP($A3,'Run1'!$A:$C,3,FALSE)<C3
```

For both approaches, take great care with the cell addresses. If you apply the format to several rows, there must not be a $ sign in front of the row number, otherwise the formula will always look at the same row and not the current row.

[image]

Edit: If you use Google Sheets, you will need to bring the comparison values into the current sheet using simple formulas like `=Sheet1!A1`, or you can put the comparison formula into the sheet. The formula will return TRUE or FALS. Then you can let the conditional formatting formula refer to THAT cell on the current sheet to set the format.

Comment: Mine is the 1st case. But when I use =$C3>Run15!$C3 , it gives invalid entry error. If I use this =$C3>"Run1!$C3" , it did not apply the required color even when the condition is true and there is no error.

Comment: What happens if you write the formula `=$C3>Run15!$C3` into a spreadsheet cell and copy down? Are the results what you expect? If so, what is your Excel version? Older versions of Excel do not allow references to other sheets in conditional formatting formulas, so you may have to bring the data into the same sheet, in a hidden column. Then use that hidden column in the CF formula.

Comment: Am using google excel and its the latest. Also, if I type the formula in the cell, I get a result like true or false. I need the cells to be coloured not true or false

Comment: There is no such thing as "Google Excel". There is Google Sheets and there is Excel. These are not the same thing and their functionality is dramatically different. Please only tag with Excel if you use Excel. If you use Google Sheets, ask on https://webapps.stackexchange.com/. It is very well possible that Google Sheets does not support off-sheet references in Conditional Formatting formulas. I don't use it. I use Excel.

Comment: ohh sure. Thank you. Will post the question on the above link.